# GUI for stockfish that can analyse the full game

Tags: analysis, engines, stockfish

I am looking for a GUI for stockfish that can analyse the whole chess game and give me the following output: For every move in the game, it should give me a list of N (let it be 3) best moves with a score corresponding to each of these moves.

Here is a [good example](https://arena.chessdom.com/games/show/stream/8152#/game/stream/8152). As you see, after each move I can see a corresponding best replies and their score. I need this to analyse a few hundred games automatically.

**P.S.** just to be clear. I do not need a software to do this with few hundred games. If it can analyse one game in the way I want, I can make it analyse all games. I just wanted to show a high level picture what I am planning to do. Sorry, that it was misleading.

Comment: Have you considered splitting that task, so the automated part can be scripted and just write the output to PGN and use any GUI to view the results?

Comment: SCID will analyze entire games.  However I don't know if it will give you 'top 3' moves.

Comment: I don't think there is any software allows you to analyse few hundred games. This is a scripting task.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible. But in a slightly crude way. It is possible with Arena Chess GUI 3.5. What you need to do is the following-

1) Open the pgn file in Arena GUI

2) Confiure any engine with Multi-PV enabled to your choice of top "N" moves.

3) Now open Engines > Automatic Analysis

4) In Source tab select "List of EPD/PGN Files" and Click the icon for adding all PGN files for which you need the automatic analysis.

5) Check "WhiteMoves" and "BlackMoves"

6) If the PGN file contains multiple PGNs then select the range of game numbers you want it to process

7) Select range of move numbers if needed

8) Now go to the Output tab and select "Write in protocol file"

9) Now start the analysis and after its done, you can check the protocol file. The last section for each move contains the best "n" moves calculated by the engine. Parsing this protocol file should be really easy if you want to automate it.

Note: The pgn itself can be altered to add the scores, but it does not add multiple moves at one shot.

Example output in the protocol file:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
16/25   00:01      3,444,292    2,274,961   -0.04   0-0 Ne5 Nc6 Nd2 Rd8 Qb3 Bd7 0-0 Qc7 Re1 h6 Ndf3 Ne4 Nxd7 Rxd7 Ne5 Bxe5 fxe5 Qb6
16/25   00:01      3,444,292    2,274,961   -0.08   Nc6 Ne5 Bd7 Nd2 0-0 Qb3 Qc7 0-0 Rfc8 Re1 h6 Ndf3 a6 Bd3 Na5 Qc2 Nc4 Bxc4 dxc4
16/25   00:01      3,444,292    2,274,961   -0.08   Bd7 Qb3 Qc7 Ne5 Nc6 Nd2 a6 0-0 0-0 Re1 Rfc8 Bd3 h6 Ndf3 Na5 Qc2 Nc4 Bxc4 dxc4
8/16/2014 12:24:59 PM, Time for this analysis: 00:00:02, Rated time: 00:04
```

Of course it also has flexibility to tailor what gets dumped into the file as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out !

http://cpuchess.com/

It's extremely simple. Just paste in you PGN text in the web interface and click for it to analyze the game. It will plot an evaluation chart which helps you to easily find blunders. Blunders are spikes in this chart, which will be highlighted in red. I'm not sure if this engine is strong or not, but it has many engines and it your machine's full processing power to analyze.

Comment: please take a look at my question. I need 3 best moves, the thing you suggest give me only one.

Answer (score 1):

**Free Creatica Chess Game Analyzer for MS Windows**
Maybe that's a solution:
  => https://chessgame-analyzer.creatica.org/index.html

Easy to use tool for  MS Windows.

Right click on a ** pgn file ** and select "Analyze". The newly created PNG file with analysis information is automatically opened in your standard chess GUI such as Scid.

Many parameters can be set for a desired result, such as the number of variants: https://chessgame-analyzer.creatica.org/customize.html

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeQ22.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Try TarraschDB analysis. Just paste the PGN, pick your move to start the analysis and click Start. It will give you the best 4 moves and you can use Capture All if you want all 4 best moves or just Capture Top to select the best move.

Link: https://www.triplehappy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Arena Chess GUI 3.5.1](http://www.playwitharena.com/?Download:Arena_3.5.1).

It works with Stockfish, and comes with built in Engines.  You can also download additional engines for it and pit them against one another in tournament mode.

Also Arena with Stockfish supports Syzygy tablebase.

It's a very strong gui.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://chess555.com . It also includes Openings Explorer and you can get games for any position up to move 20.